# Ordering Strings in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, alphabetical

I have an assignment where i am supposed to create an object that initializes an array of strings to have "size" elements and the amount of used elements equal to 0.

my issue is when im trying to compare strings to put them in alphabetical order.

```
int compare = storage[index].compareTo(value);
if (compare < 0)
```

thats where i am getting the runtime error of a nullpointerexception

here is my full code.

class main

```
package assignment2;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OrderedStringList myList = new OrderedStringList(5);

        System.out.println("adding 10, 5, & 7");
        myList.Insert("10");
        myList.Insert("5");
        myList.Insert("7");

        myList.Display();

        System.out.println("Value 4 find = "+ myList.Find("4"));
        System.out.println("Value 7 find = "+ myList.Find("7"));

        System.out.println("Adding 24 & 3");
        myList.Insert("24");
        myList.Insert("3");

        myList.Display();

        System.out.println("myList size: "+ myList.Size());

        if (!myList.Insert("12"))
            System.out.println("Could not add 12, full");

        System.out.println("Removing 10, adding 12.");
        myList.Delete("10");
        myList.Insert("12");

        myList.Display();
    }
}
```

class OrderedStringList

```
package assignment2;
public class OrderedStringList {
    int length;
    int numUsed;
    String[] storage;
    boolean ordered;

    public OrderedStringList(int size){
        length = size;
        storage = new String[length];
        numUsed = 0;
    }


    public boolean Insert(String value){
        boolean result = false;
                int index = 0;
                if (numUsed < length) {
                    while (index <= numUsed) {
                        int compare = storage[index].compareTo(value);
                        if (compare < 0)
                            index++;
                    }
                    moveItemsDown(index);
                    storage[index] = value;
                    numUsed++;
                    result = true;
                }
                return result;
    }
    private void moveItemsDown(int start){
        int index;
        for (index = numUsed-1; index >=start; index--){
            storage[index+1] = storage[index];
        }
    }

    private void moveItemsUp(int start){
        int index;
        for (index = start; index < numUsed-1; index++){
            storage[index] = storage[index+1];
        }
    }

    public boolean Find(String value){
        return (FindIndex(value) >= 0);
    }

    private int FindIndex(String value) {
        int result = -1;
        int index = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        while ((index < numUsed) && (!found)) {
            found = (value.equals(storage[index]));
            if (!found)
                index++;
        }
        if (found)
            result = index;
        return result;
    }

    public boolean Delete(String value){
        boolean result = false;
        int location;
        location = FindIndex(value);
        if (location >= 0) {
            moveItemsUp(location);
            numUsed--;
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void Display() {
        int index;
        System.out.println("list Contents: ");
        for (index = 0; index < numUsed; index++) {
            System.out.println(index+" "+storage[index]);
        }
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void DisplayNoLF() {
        int index;
        System.out.println("list Contents: ");
        for (index = 0; index < numUsed; index++) {
            System.out.print(storage[index]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public int Size(){
        return numUsed;
    }
}
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's why:

```
public boolean Insert(String value){
    boolean result = false;
            int index = 0;
            if (numUsed < length) {
                while (index <= numUsed) { // Here the first time numUsed = 0, index = 0, index <= numUsed;
                    int compare = storage[index].compareTo(value); // The first time, storage[0] == null; NullPointException is thrown
                    if (compare < 0)
                        index++;
                }
                moveItemsDown(index);
                storage[index] = value;
                numUsed++;
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
}
```

Maybe change `<=` to `<` will do?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
while(index < numUsed)
```

If you use <=, you'll always access index 0 in an empty list, which will be null.  Then when you try to call compareTo on it it will throw an NPE.

ALso, if null is a legal value to add to your list, you'll need to put a null check around the compareTo call and decide if null is alphabetically first or last.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Arrays#sort` to maintain order, its already available in library.

```
public boolean Insert(String value){
    boolean result = false;

    if (numUsed < length) {
        storage[index] = value;
        numUsed++;
        result = true;
        Arrays.sort(storage); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: this is something i would generally do, except this is a college class and we are supposed to be learning something. haha

Answer (score 0):

At the first run this line

```
int compare = storage[index].compareTo(value);
```

your are comparing `storage[index]` which value is `null` with `value` which is `not null or empty`

to enable a smooth running 
replace

```
          while(index =< numUsed) {
        int compare = storage[index].compareTo(value);
        if(compare < 0)
            index++;
    }
```

with

```
 while(index < numUsed) {
        int compare = storage[index].compareTo(value);
        if(compare < 0)
            index++;
    }
```